ReactVite Express NodeJs Azure app service. 404 The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable
Error: 404 Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
I have deployed a simple webapp to Azure app service. base url works fine but when I try to hit baseurl/hello endpoint I get the error.
Setup works locally, but I have been pondering my brains out to figure how I can get express to redirect requests in Azure.
web.config
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- SPA fallback rule to handle client-side routing -->
        <rule name="SPA Routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <!-- Exclude /hello and any other endpoints -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/hello" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

package.json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w src/server -x tsx src/server/main.ts",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tsx src/server/main.ts",
    "build": "vite build && cpx web.config dist/"

server/main.ts
import express from "express";
import ViteExpress from "vite-express";

const app = express();

app.get("/hello", (_, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Vite + React + TypeScript!");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
ViteExpress.listen(app, +port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
);

project structure image. local, dist included
Azure App Service, wwwroot folder via Kudu

Are you deploying your app to Azure Web Apps or Azure Container Apps?

Can you please provide your project structure.

@AsleshaKantamsetti- It is an Azure Web App deployed on Azure App Service running on Windows via IIS.

@AsleshaKantamsetti- local project structure is appfolder{[dist], [node_modules],[src(client[app.ts], server[main.ts])]} and on Azure App Service where its deployed I have ./wwwroor/[index.html, web.config,(assets[index.js])]

added project structure images in the description above.

As you're deploying your app to Windows, Use Require() in your main.ts instead of import method to import package.

Windows didn't support import method after deployment.

If possible, share your GitHub repository?

Are you deploying your frontend and backend separately?

When I tried your code, even I was unable to redirect to /hello endpoint in Azure App Service.
I added the below lines of code to the main.ts file. this setup serves all static files from the dist folder and allowing the front-end framework to handle the route.
import path from 'path';


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist', 'index.html'));
});

Below is the complete code of main.ts.
src/server/main.ts:
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import ViteExpress from 'vite-express';
const app = express();
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist')));
app.get('/hello', (_, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Vite + React + TypeScript!');
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist', 'index.html'));
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
ViteExpress.listen(app, +port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
);

In local environment vite-express handles both server and client, but in azure we need to define /hello route in vite.config.ts.
vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/hello': {
        target: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

package.json:
{
  "name": "my-vite-express-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w src/server -x tsx src/server/main.ts",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tsx src/server/main.ts",
    "build": "vite build && cpx web.config dist/"
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "vite-express": "^0.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "tsx": "^4.19.2",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.10"
  }
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}

After changing main.ts, I am successfully redirected to the /hello endpoint.
Azure Web App Output:



@aamer saleem Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Perfect!, yes. I was missing the routing config in vite.config.ts. Additionally, I was also missing tsconfig.json to my deployed app during my build process.

@NaveenSharma- done, thank you for the link
